# How to average data over strings basing on the first element of the string in python

Tags: python, list, average

(Sorry for my English in advance)
I have a text file read by python:

```
with open("Input2010_5a.txt", "r") as file:
for line in file:
    date, long, lat, depth, temp, sal = line.split("\t")
    line_data = []
    line_data.append(float(date))
    line_data.append(float(long))
    line_data.append(float(lat))
    line_data.append(float(depth))
    line_data.append(float(temp))
    line_data.append(float(sal))
```

As a result I get 41 lists looking like this:

[picture of a list I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKNBM.jpg)

The first one is a date, and I need to average all the rest numbers by a date. I mean if I have several 2010.36, the other variables in every list containing 2010.36 should be avaraged. In this way I should get 3 lists as a result: averaged over 2010.36, 2010,37, 2010.38.
Please, help me!

Comment: Can you at least paste the sample of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can build a dictionary mapping dates to list of entries.  Once we have all the data in our dictionary, we can take the averages of each value for each date

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open("Input2010_5a.txt", "r") as file:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for line in file:
        date, *data = map(float, line.split())
        d[date].append(data)

averages = {date: [sum(values)/len(values) for values in zip(*entries)] for date, entries in d.items()}
```

For data

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
1 1 1 1
```

this gives me

```
print(averages)
# {1.0: [1.5, 2.0, 2.5], 2.0: [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]}
```